# Install4j, how can I fix "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/install4j/runtime/launcher/Launcher"

Tags: macos, java, freebsd

I've just downloaded install4j version 5, as my previously working version 4 no longer works with my new JRE, but now I can't get it to do anything other than this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/install4j/runtime/launcher/Launcher
```

I've tried this on OS X 10.6 with the bundled Java 6 and OpenJDK7 (both 32 and 64 bit ver.)
I've also tried this on a FreeBSD 8 server running Java 6 64 bit.

Nothing else meaningful is spit-up by the install4jc executable.
Any suggestions??

Thanks :)